# How to mark a test as pendingUntilFixed with SpecWithJUnit

Tags: scala, testing, tdd, specs2

```
import org.specs2.mutable.SpecWithJUnit
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import org.specs2.execute.Failure
class MyTest extends SpecWithJUnit {
  trait Context extends Scope
  "myClass" should {
    "work but not right now" in new Context {
       Failure("test fails")
    }
  }
}
```

In this Specs2 example, how do I mark the test as pending until fixed (as I would with SpecificationWithJUnit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `PendingUntilFixed` trait:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.SpecWithJUnit
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import org.specs2.execute.{PendingUntilFixed, Failure}

class TestSpec extends SpecWithJUnit with PendingUntilFixed {
  trait Context extends Scope
  "myClass" should {
    "work but not right now" in new Context {
      failure("test fails")
    }.pendingUntilFixed("for now")
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works. Is there any documentation explaining that?

Comment: `PendingUntilFixed` is [there](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.3/org.specs2.guide.PendingUntilFixedExamples.html) and "lightweight specs" are described [here](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.3/org.specs2.guide.LightweightSpecs.html). On the other hand the doc doesn't mention that you have to add the `PendingUntilFixed` trait on lightweight specs.